# How to give tags to multiple posts?

Tags: php, api, blogs, metaweblog

I have a question that I really want to know.
I am running a textcube-based (https://github.com/needlworks/textcube) blog, and I want to give (set) tags to multiple posts at once.

I tried to achive this using MetaWeblog API and PHP, but I can't find a way to set tags. (My blogging platform supports Blogger v1, MetaWeblog, Movable Type API)

I know Wordpress can give tags to multiple posts at once, but my blogging platform doesn't have this feature (can only edit tags in the "Edit post" interface - can only edit one post's tag at a time).

Is there anyway to do it using MetaWeblog API (or similar API)?
Or blogging software?

I need your help!
Thanks in advance.